# Footnote with url in caption?

Tags: captions, footnotes, texmaker, urls

I try to put a url as a reference in a caption of a figure. But it seem to give all kinds of errors like:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \contentsline was complete.
```

Is there  a way to make this work?

```
\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{image}
    \caption{
         \footnote{\url{test.com}}
                }
    \label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Footnotes to captions don't really make sense. Why not simply set the URL *in* the caption?

Comment: I think it is kind of ugly, a long url with signs in (not as short as the example).

Comment: It will be uglier in a footnote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of `footnotemark` and `footnotetext`. Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{image}
    \caption[Caption for LOC]{Real caption\footnotemark}
    \label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}
Anywhere on page where float appears\footnotetext{\url{test.com}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the footnote will appear in the same page as the figure.

Comment: @egreg No it does not. But if you put it close it will not happen often, and in rare occasions when it happen you can move `footnotetext` before figure or move it around so it is on the same page.

Comment: It did not work in the image code that I had already. But removing it and using this worked!

Comment: For me, this did not work too if I put the code suggested by @Tahtisilma but not if I do it myself in a subfigure environment. 

What I was missing was the `[` brackets before the `Real caption\footnotemark`